# Is there a way to get CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MySQL 8 in the format of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS instead of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to get `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in MySQL 8 in the format of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS instead of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

`SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` is returning `2021-04-20 15:33:11` currently.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use `DATE_FORMAT` like for all other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numeric context:

```sql
SELECT 0 + CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Comment: Can you share more details about this such that others can learn from your answer?

Comment: @NicoHaase Link to Reference Manual added.

Comment: What makes the `SELECT 0 +` format it this way?

Comment: @EthanAllen This sets that the expression have numeric (not string/date/etc.) context. This instructs the server to cast all operands to numeric datatype implicitly. TIMESTAMP value is converted to numeric value according to the rules described in RM by the link: *a number in either YYYYMMDDhhmmss or YYMMDDhhmmss format*, by default 4-digit year representation (which is not ambiguous) is used. Of course you may use explicit cast instead: `SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS UNSIGNED);` - it performs the same operation but needs more chars.

Answer (score 1):

yes , using `DATE_FORMAT` function

```
select DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
```

output:

20210420154359